# H2: How to create a linked table from Oracle view?

Tags: oracle, h2

How to create a linked table from Oracle view? I can create linked table from Oracle table by code below

```
--TEST is a table in Oracle
CREATE LINKED TABLE LINK('', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:1521:se', 'sa', 'sa', '(SELECT * FROM TEST)');
```

But when I change table `TEST` to view `VIEW_TEST` as below,

```
--VIEW_TEST is an view in Oracle
CREATE LINKED TABLE LINK('', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:1521:se', 'sa', 'sa', '(SELECT * FROM VIEW_TEST)');
```

exception will throw: *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*.

So How to create a linked table from Oracle view?

**update:**

If the I change the view to materialized view, it is also work.

```
--MV_TEST is a materialized view in Oracle
CREATE LINKED TABLE LINK('', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:1521:se', 'sa', 'sa', '(SELECT * FROM MV_TEST)');
```

Comment: The error is pretty straight foward. It means either the view does not exist or user `sa` does not have grant (privileges) to it. Try to add grants to this view to the user sa and let us know

Comment: Actually, it's not the privilege problem. I find it's also OK if the view is materialized view. Please see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the H2 documentation about Linked table is not clear enough about views. My guess is, as it worked with materialized view, it only works with physical objects. A view on oracle is not a physical object, it is a link resource to a query on the database.

As the docs states the cases which [LINKED TABLE](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#linked_tables) will not work

> The following are not supported because they may result in a deadlock: creating a linked table to the same database, and creating a linked table to another database using the server mode if the other database is open in the same server (use the embedded mode instead).
>
> Data types that are not supported in H2 are also not supported for linked tables, for example unsigned data types if the value is outside the range of the signed type. In such cases, the columns needs to be cast to a supported type.

So, it is not clear whether accepts views or not.

The best you can do is to try the `FORCE` command as the **[documentation states](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_linked_table)** that it will create the linked table even if the table does not exists. So it will be like:

```
CREATE FORCE LINKED 
    TABLE LINK ( '', 
                 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:1521:se', 
                 'sa', 
                 'sa', 
                 '(SELECT * FROM VIEW_TEST)' );
```

Comment: Yes, we need to put the view into parenthesis, like `'(VIEW_TEST)'`, it will work. Thanks for your answer.